# Compare 2 List of objects java

Tags: java

I need to compare 2 Lists of the same type of object. Can I get suggestion on which is the fastest method.

E.g

```
public class Cars {
String engine;
String brand;
String etc ..;
```

I got method compareCars(List a, List b) that returns true if there is a single occurrence in which the Cars in both are the same.

Comment: Please post the code of your compareCars method. Also, clarify what you want to know, because this is very unclear

Comment: It depends on characteristics of data ... if lists has the same size and same order then you have to compare a[i] with b[i] for every i in set(0, N) ... looks like a basic programming excercise

Comment: I don't actually have the code for the compare method, that's my question how to compare the 2 lists of objects. But I was thinking maybe using:

for (each Car in List a)
    for(each Car in List b)
           if equals {
               //do something
}

Comment: Try some methods, compute the execution time, conclude. If you are not satisfied, show us what you tried, telling you came up with this solution which doesn't fit your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Class name should be singular - **Car**.

```
    I suggest the following code.
```

You can override hashCode() and equals() to get compare two cars as you wanted.

```
boolean compareCars(List<Car> cars1, List<Car> cars2) {
    boolean isSingleOccuranceMatch = false;
    for (Car car : cars1) {
        if (cars2.contains(car)) {
            isSingleOccuranceMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isSingleOccuranceMatch;
}
```

No need of variable isSingleoccuranceMatch.

```
    This is just for readability.
```

You can directly return true instead of break and return false after completing all the iterations.

Using Java8, no need of any method

```
cars1.stream().filter(car1 -> cars2.contains(car1) ).count() > 0
```